# nstimer count down not working as expected

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, nstimer

I am using `nstimer` to show count down timer in a label. I am able to start the timer and show the count down in the label but the timer jumps to next second rather than showing every second. If the count down timer is set to 10 sec then it shows only 9,7,5,3,1 in the count down timer label.

Below is my code.

```
 NSTimer *tktTimer;
 int secondsLeft;


- (void)startTimer {
   secondsLeft = 10;
        tktTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateCountdown) userInfo:nil repeats: YES];
}

-(void) updateCountdown {
    int hours, minutes, seconds;

    secondsLeft--;
    NSLog(@"secondsLeft %d",secondsLeft);//every time it is printing 9,7,5,3,1 but should print 9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0
    hours = secondsLeft / 3600;
    minutes = (secondsLeft % 3600) / 60;
    seconds = (secondsLeft %3600) % 60;
    countDownlabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds];


    if (--secondsLeft == 0) {
        [tktTimer invalidate];
        countDownlabel.text = @"Completed";
    }


}
```

Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`--secondsLeft` updates the variable. To check if the next decrement will be 0, use `if (secondsLeft - 1 == 0)`

Each tick is decrementing the variable twice.

Additionally, this will trigger the "Completed" text on 1, not 0. Below is a better way to handle this:

```
-(void) updateCountdown {
    int hours, minutes, seconds;

    secondsLeft--;
    if (secondsLeft == 0) {
        [tktTimer invalidate];
        countDownlabel.text = @"Completed";
        return;
    }        
    NSLog(@"secondsLeft %d",secondsLeft);//every time it is printing 9,7,5,3,1 but should print 9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0
    hours = secondsLeft / 3600;
    minutes = (secondsLeft % 3600) / 60;
    seconds = (secondsLeft %3600) % 60;
    countDownlabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds];
}
```

Comment: If i use this if condition then i am facing the problems to invalidate the timer .Can you edit your answer by showing the code to invalidate the timer.

Comment: looking back at the code and how it works, this would fire on "1" rather than "0" - just checking if it's 0 would be better. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score -1):

//sweet and simple way to perform timer with easy and understandable code

DECLARE

```
 int seconds;
 NSTimer *timer;
```

//in viewDidLoad method

```
seconds=12;
     timer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(GameOver) userInfo:nil repeats:YES ];

-(void)GameOver
{
     seconds-=1;
     lblUpTimer.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",seconds];//shows counter in label

if(seconds==0)
[timer invalidate];
}
```

THANK YOU

Comment: Although this shows how to use a scheduledTimer, it doesn't tell the OP what the problem was and how this helps him/her.